# Allowed values for $x$ in $\log_2(x)$

Tags: functions, logarithms

$$y=\log_2x$$

What are the allowed values for $x$ in this function? How do I calculate it? (I know how it works for normal functions with fractions and other stuff, but this one I'm stuck)

Comment: You are only allowed to enter positive numbers into a logarithm and so the allowed values of $x$ are $x > 0$, or in interval notation $(0,\infty)$. As far as calculating goes, note that $y = \log_2 x$ if and only if $2^y = x$, by definition. Therefore, to find the value of $\log_2 x$, you ask yourself, "What do I raise $2$ to, to get $x$?"

Comment: @Suugaku So, basically I have to solve the equation 2^x = x?

Comment: Well, $2^y = x$ for $y$, but yeah. For example, $\log_2 (64) = 6$. This is because if $\log_2(64) = y$, then $2^y = 64$, and the value of $y$ that gives this is $6$.

Comment: @user95523 You have an $x$, then you have to find a $y$ such that $2^y=x$.

Comment: So, basically logx = 2, we multiply by 10 and we get 10^logx = 10^2, x=100?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good example too for solving log equations. Although, you're not technically multiplying by 10, but taking both sides and raising 10 to them.

Comment: So, in this example, I have to do : 2^y = x. So that means, Df = (0, +infinity)

Comment: Yep, in general you always set whatever is inside of the log greater than zero. For example, if you have $y = \log_b(27x + 54)$, you would solve $27 x + 54 > 0$ to get $x > -1/2$ as the domain. The base actually doesn't matter when finding domain, but only the horizontal shift and stretch/shrink.

Comment: @Suugaku Thanks a lot, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Definition: $\log_ax = n$ means that $a^n = x$

$$y=\log_2x \implies 2^y = x$$

With logarithmic functions, $(\log x)$, $x$ is only allowed to be positive i.e. $x>0$. So for instance, $\log -1$ does not exist. To calculate, you would change the $\log$ function, in your case to $2^y = x$, where if you had a value of $x$, you can now easily find the value of $y$ whether by intuition (if you had $2^y = 2$, then clearly the only value $y$ can be is $1$) or by some scratch-work for more difficult or harder to see equations.